# Array of Dictionary for dates

Tags: arrays, swift, date, dictionary

I am trying to have an array of dictionaries of type string : int.
I am trying to initialize that array with dates for an year (as string) and 0 (for all the ints).

However, I am facing various errors. The compiler thinks that my print statement is ambiguous.

My code:

```
class Dates {
    static func printDatesBetweenInterval(_ startDate: Date, _ endDate: Date) -> [Dictionary<String, Int>] {
        var details = [Dictionary<String, Int>]()
        var startDate = startDate
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        while startDate <= endDate {
            let sDate =  fmt.string(from: startDate)
            print (sDate)
            details.append([sDate : 0])
            startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!
        }

        return details
    }

    static func dateFromString(_ dateString: String) -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
    }
}

struct Attendee {
    var masterStudentdetails = [Dictionary<String, Int>]()

    init() {
        masterStudentdetails = Dates.printDatesBetweenInterval(Dates.dateFromString("2018-08-22"), Dates.dateFromString("2019-08-20"))
        for (dayStr, trackNum) in masterStudentdetails {
            print(dayStr) //This line is causes error.
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to execute code outside of a function scope. You need to wrap all lines after `var masterStudentdetails = [Dictionary<String, Int>]()` in a function.

Comment: It is actually in init func -- my mistake. Post is updated

Answer (score 0):

`masterStudentDetails` is an array of dictionary. So your `for in` is giving a result of `[String: Int]`, not a key-value pair.

You need to iterate the array and then iterate the key-value pairs in each dictionary.

```
init() {
    masterStudentdetails = Dates.printDatesBetweenInterval(Dates.dateFromString("2018-08-22"), Dates.dateFromString("2019-08-20"))
    for dictionary in masterStudentdetails {
        for (dayStr, trackNum) in dictionary.enumerated() {
            print(dayStr)
        }
    }
}
```

But since you only have one key-value pair in each dictionary, you can do:

```
init() {
    masterStudentdetails = Dates.printDatesBetweenInterval(Dates.dateFromString("2018-08-22"), Dates.dateFromString("2019-08-20"))
    for dictionary in masterStudentdetails {
        if let pair = dictionary.first {
            print(pair.key)
        }
    }
}
```